# SQL - list of student ids and average mark in 2 decimal places

Tags: sql, average

Question: Write a query to display list of student ids and average mark in 2 decimal places if their average mark is greater than 80. Give an alias to average mark as avg_mark. Sort the result based on average mark.

[Schema for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6SOS.png)

I wrote this query, but the result doesn't match the expected output.

```
select student_id, round(avg(value)) as avg_mark 
from mark
where value>80    -------well this is wrong as I need to compare with an average of value
group by student_id
order by avg_mark
```

Running this query gives wrong output [linked below]

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEiVL.png)

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

You want `having` rather than `where`:

```
select student_id, round(avg(value)) as avg_mark 
from mark
group by student_id
having avg(value) > 80 
order by avg_mark
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function instead

```
round(avg(value), 2)
```

This will help

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work fine.

```
select student_id, cast(avg(value) as decimal(10,2)) as avg_mark from mark
group by student_id
having avg(value)>80
order by avg_mark;
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select student_id, round(avg(value)) as avg_mark 
from mark
group by student_id
having avg(value) > 80
group by student_id 
order by avg_mark
```

Answer (score -2):

select studid, FirstName, trunc(months_between(sysdate,dob)/12) as Age from student order by studid;

Comment: Hello @user15795958. Welcome to SO. Please consider taking a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in order to potentially improve your answer. One simple improvement would be to format the code in your answer, by putting it in a code block.